# How do I setpassword to compressed zip files in Python

Tags: python, passwords, zip

I get this error when I try to set a password to a zip file. Below is the code/error I get. Please give me an example of the correct way to do it.

- This is just the password part of the script... the entire script is to long to post.

Code:

```
password = "dog" 
password = zipfile.setpassword(pwd)

Error received when hitting the password part of the script.
-------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ZIP-IT\ZIP IT.py", line 86, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ZIP-IT\ZIP IT.py", line 54, in start
    compress()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\ZIP-IT\ZIP IT.py", line 70, in compress
    password = zipfile.setpassword(pwd)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'setpassword'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you running Python 2.6+?

---

### [ZipFile.setpassword(pwd)](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.setpassword)

Set pwd as default password to extract encrypted files.

**New in version 2.6.**

---

The [Python zipfile docs](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) say at the top that they "[support] *decryption* of encrypted files in ZIP archives, but it currently **cannot create** an encrypted file."

Comment: Colorized like what? In your original post another member (pyfunc) edited it using the code formatting tool (adds 4 spaces before all the lines) which marks it as "code", then some fancy JavaScript colors it.

Answer (score -1):

You need to reference the particular zip, instead of the module.

```
zpf = zipfile.ZipFile('your file path')
password = "dog" 
password = zpf.setpassword(pwd)
```